Blender Geometry Nodes，Change the orientation of the instances on the points
In Blender Geometry Nodes, I scattered the faces of a cube into points and placed a plane on each point. How can I make these planes inherit the orientation of the corresponding faces of the original cube? Is there something wrong with the way I captured the attributes?

NEW tried 


NO　rotation 

The original mesh 


Apply the sacle 


Do you mean "I scattered the faces of a cube with points" ? Or do you keep the cube corners, and you are looking for the average normal of the faces connected to each corner ? Do you try a Distribute Points on Faces node instead ?

No, I used the Mesh to Points node. Now, I will try using the Distribute Points on Faces node. I want to change each point into a plane, but I need these newly generated planes to inherit the orientation of the original mesh.

And thank you for your helpful comment！

Yeah, you can't get the "Normal" of the "Points", because points don't have normals.

You must get the normals from the original "Faces".

But seriously....aren't you just looking for a "split edges" node?

Edit - fixing your second try
There are two issues with your second try:

First (in blue), the "selection" on mesh to points "is changing the point count" AND the index of the points. This will create wrong results for the "sample index" node.

You need the selection to go straight into "instance on points", so the point count remains the same as the meshes, and the "index" node matches


Second (in yellow x red), the domain of your "sample index" is face (yellow), it will work well for the points you put on "faces", but it will not work for the points that were "vertices" (red)

You need another "sample index" on the "point" domain for the vertices themselves.





Thank you for your comment! I tried your example, but the mesh became deformed. Could you tell me how to keep the mesh unchanged? "I will upload  new Content Screenshot

Apply your scale.

Thank you for your comment too !  The mesh is no longer deforming, but the orientation of the cones is still incorrect. I am currently working on resolving this issue.

@user208244, try the suggested changes on the edited answer

@DanielMöller ,Thank you very much! The problem is now resolved, and the generated planes are all oriented correctly. Next, I might try making them scale or move outward along the normals. However, I feel that my foundational knowledge is still lacking, so I will continue trying to deepen my understanding.

Scale is easily done by connecting something to the scale in the "instance on points", placing them outwards is easily done by editing the "origin" of the plane to somewhere below it.
